# Cannot redeclare Custom Method

Tags: php

I <del>randomly</del> vary rarely get reports from users with this problem:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare my_thing() (previously declared in /foo/functions.php:9) in /foo/functions.php on line 21
```

This is the function in that file:

```
function my_thing( $subclass = null ) {
    global $my_thing;

    $args = func_get_args();
    $subclass = array_shift( $args );

    if ( is_null( $subclass ) ) {
        return $my_thing;
    }

    return call_user_func_array( array( $my_thing, $subclass ), $args );

}
```

The first line of this block is line #9 in `functions.php` and the last closing bracket is line #21.

So how could be `my_thing()` be declared **twice on line #21**? Even if the functions.php get included twice (for whatever reason) the line should be #9 and not #21.

The functions.php file is `require_once` in the bootstrap file.

*sidenote*: this is a wrapper method so I can call class method easily like `my_thing('subclass')->get_it()`

Comment: Could it just be that you include the PHP file, in which `function my_thing()` is declared, twice? Better use `include_once()` or `require_once()` to prevent this.

Comment: The function is only fully defined after the last brace in line 21, but the declaration starts at line 9. So it's understandable that the error is created in line 21, and refers to the duplicate in line 9. I would guess the file is included twice. Maybe use `require_once` instead of `require`.

Comment: Thanks but the functions.php file is loaded with `require_once`

Comment: As KIKO software said it sounds like you are including files that also have the functions file included so its getting included twice and, im also wondering why your not using `spl_autoload_register` and creating your own method.

Comment: Yes, seems legit @Parody but that's another topic ;) I cannot touch the codebase right now.